# How to filter an array of words that includes a specific string pattern and of words that are in another array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of words. I can enter a text in an input field, and the array will be filtered based on my request. This is the easy part.

Now, I can also select one of the word proposed and push it into another array of selected words. As soon as a word goes into the selected array, it should not be available anymore.

I wrote this:

```js
const words = ["hello", "allo", "test", "cool", "top"]
const selected = ["hello"]

const availableWords = (term) => words.filter((w,i)=> w.includes(term) && !selected[i].includes(term))

availableWords("llo")
// expected output: ["allo"]
// actual output: "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined"
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The `i` in your code is not the index. I am also unclear on what you are trying to do. A little more explanation will help.

Comment: Spec seems somewhat unclear. What happens if the substring (i.e. `"allo"`) matches multiple words in `words`? What if it matches none? I strongly recommend against writing functions that mutate global state. If you need to persist state, encapsulate data in an object or function, or at least use parameters and return values.

Comment: @Yathi I'm doing a basic autocomplete from a list of options. Words could be countries for example. A words appears if it include a part or the totality of the query (usa would show up if I type "sa" for exemple). Then, if I select "usa", I don't want it anymore in my array of words, since the option has already been selected. This where I'm stuck.

Comment: @ggorlen all words that includes "allo" (for exemple "allohomora" and "allo" are true) are returned. But if the array `selected` includes "allohomora", only "allo" should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the found word of selected if the actual word match.

```js
const
    availableWords = term => words.filter(w => w.includes(term) && !selected.includes(w)),
    words = ["hello", "allo", "test", "cool", "top"],
    selected = ["hello"];


console.log(availableWords("llo")); // ["allo"]
```

Comment: @Andreas, no, because it checks `w` instead of `term`.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't solve the usecase here. I need to check if one of the word of `selected` includes at least a part of the query. For exemple, "usa" includes "sa".

Comment: @DoneDeal0, can you add some use cases to the question?

Comment: Well, eventually, the simplest option is to remove the selected element with splice, so I'll just abandon this strategy. However, the question remain interesting. The detailed usecase is written above, in answer to Yathi.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 Nina's answer works. `w` is the current element being processed in the array. The first condition (of the `filter()` callback) checks if the element includes the _term_ ("llo" in the example) and the second condition checks if the "selected" array contains the _element_ (i.e., "hello" in the example).

Comment: @charles no because selected would return false if it contains "usa" but my request is "sa". "usa" !== "sa".

Comment: @DoneDeal0 If your request is "sa" then `w.includes(term)` reads like "usa includes sa". If that's true then `selected.includes(w)` will read like "selected array includes usa". The second condition is testing for **the element** and **not the term**. The second condition will be tested only if the first condition is satisfied.

Comment: please add more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is what you want:

```js
let availableWord2 = (term) => words.filter(w => !selected.includes(w))
                                    .filter(w => w.includes(term))

availableWord2('llo') //["allo"]
```

**Explanation**: The first filter filters out all the words that are already selected. The second filter then searches for the word entered from the remaining list.